# Get color of pixel of existing base64-image via canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Got a image inside of a HTML document. Source is a base64 string. I want to retrieve the color of the pixel that is clicked on. Using a memory canvas all I get is zeros.

```
 function getColor(imagecontainer,top,left){
     var image = new Image();
     image.onload = function() {
         var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
         var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
         context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
         var myData = context.getImageData(Math.round(left)-2, Math.round(top)-2, 4, 4).data;
         console.log(myData, left, top);
     };
     image.src = imagecontainer.find("img").attr("src");  
 }
```

There are many other questions regarding the same problem, however none of the solutions could solve this problem for me. MyData always contains zeros.

Comment: Are you trying to get 1 or 16 (as here) pixels?

Comment: Yeah, thats a bit confusing to read, I am later interpolating the 16 pixels..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** based on new information:

The cause could simply be that the main image (imagecontainer.find("img")) isn't loaded at the time it is references.

If this image exists in DOM you can use windows.onload to run your script:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // code that uses the image
};
```

as this will run only when everything has loaded incl. image data. Optionally add an inline onload handler to the image tag (not recommended), or add the src via JavaScript and monitor the onload event there.

Another possible cause is that if this is IE and the image is in the cache, onload may not trigger. You can check the image's `complete` property to check for this:

```
 var image = new Image();
 image.onload = onloadHandler;
 image.src = imagecontainer.find("img").attr("src");  
 if (image.complete) onloadHandler();

function onloadHandler() {
     var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
     var myData = context.getImageData(Math.round(left)-2, Math.round(top)-2, 4, 4).data;
 };
```

Although you can use this directly with the original image without loading another with the same url.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I left all the error checking out to keep the code more readable on here. If the image is already loaded the onload is never triggered I guess. So if I use the image itself I dont need the onload. Well, however I always get an array of zeros.

Comment: @dboth I suspect the main image hasn't even loaded.. does your script run on windows.onload?